# Is there a limit to the ArrayBuffer size of chrome.hid.send?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, hid

The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid#method-send) do not seem to mention any such limit but I am getting strange errors when I try to send a 64 byte-long message.  All other message transfers seem to work fine.

Not that I think it is really relevant to the question being asked, but here is my `send` method within the `COMMS` namespace in case there is an obvious error that I should be aware of:

```
// Transmits the given data
//
// @param[in] outData,       The data to send as an ArrayBuffer
// @param[in] onTxCompleted, The method called on completion of the outgoing transfer.  The return
//                           code is passed as a string.
// @param[in] onRxCompleted, The method called on completion of the incoming transfer.  The return
//                           code is passed as a string along with the response as an ArrayBuffer.
send: function(outData, onTxCompleted, onRxCompleted) {
  if (-1 === connection_) {
    console.log("Attempted to send data with no device connected.");
    return;
  }

  if (0 == outData.byteLength) {
    console.log("Attempted to send nothing.");
    return;
  }

  if (COMMS.receiving) {
    console.log("Waiting for a response to a previous message.  Aborting.");
    return;
  }

  if (COMMS.transmitting) {
    console.log("Waiting for a previous message to finish sending.  Aborting.");
    return;
  }

  COMMS.transmitting = true;
  chrome.hid.send(connection_, REPORT_ID, outData, function() {
    COMMS.transmitting = false;

    if (onTxCompleted) {
      onTxCompleted(chrome.runtime.lastError ? chrome.runtime.lastError.message : '');
    }

    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log('Error in COMMS.send: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }

    // Register a response handler if one is expected
    if (onRxCompleted) {
      COMMS.receiving = true;
      chrome.hid.receive(connection_, function(reportId, inData) {
        COMMS.receiving = false;
        onRxCompleted(chrome.runtime.lastError ? chrome.runtime.lastError.message : '', inData);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What type of HID device? What does its USB descriptor say the maximum packet size is?

Comment: Unfortunately a custom device.  The properties from the HidDeviceInfo object read "maxInputReportSize":64,"maxOutputReportSize":64

Comment: Possible that the device itself is at fault? Are you sure it can accept and properly handle 64-byte packets?

Comment: I've been testing sending 64B messages with a command that expects a response (and has a response callback specified), but it's been failing no matter what I try for a command that does not have a reply.  Size has been tested to NOT be the issue.  A new issue may have happened after an update.  Not sure if I should close question or change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a device whose properties from the `HidDeviceInfo` read `"maxInputReportSize":64,"maxOutputReportSize":64`, there **does NOT seem to be an additional limit imposed by `chrome.hid.send`.**  But something does seem to be awry.

Using the method in the OP, I can successfully send a message that prompts one back from the device.  I currently am unable to send an outgoing message only.  I wish the `chrome.lastError.message` was a little more detailed than `Transfer Failed`.